# The unique attributes of Core Data in iOS and Mac OS

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I have two project with same code to test the behaviors of uniques attributes in iOS and Mac OS and find they are different.

First, I created a entity named `Person` and added a attribute `name` to it. Then added this attribute to the `constraints`.

Second, I added `[_managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];`
 to `- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext` in `AppDelegate.m`.

At last, I modify the `viewDidLoad` in `ViewController.m` as follow:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// NSApplication for Mac OS
Person *salary = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:sharedDelegate.managedObjectContext];

[salary setName:@"a"];

[sharedDelegate.managedObjectContext save:nil];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];

NSArray *result = [[sharedDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[result count]);
for (Person *item in result) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[item name]);
}

}
```

After I run these two project several times, I found that the uniqueness of attribute is guaranteed in iOS while is incorrect in Mac OS. Was it a existed bug , or I have done the test in wrong way?