# Mac OS X Core Data distinct values

Tags: macos, core-data, realm

I'm building a Mac OS X application where I'm storing a number of records in core data (i'm also trying in realm), I have a made up example below:

```
  Num  | rate | factor |
_______|______|________|
   1   |  3.2 |    4   |
   2   |  5.5 |    7   |
   2   |  2.1 |    2   |
   2   |  3.1 |    2   |
   3   |  4.5 |    5   |
   1   |  2.3 |    4   |
```

I want to get the first row for each `Num` field. So the result should be as below:

```
  Num  | rate | factor |
_______|______|________|
   1   |  3.2 |    4   |
   2   |  5.5 |    7   |
   3   |  4.5 |    5   |
```

What is the most efficient way to do the above fetch? I have read the following on this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/

[The unique attributes of Core Data in iOS and Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242446/the-unique-attributes-of-core-data-in-ios-and-mac-os)

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

A simple use case would be as in Messages (for Mac) where it shows the latest message on the left side and the phone number associated with it. It simply does a group by on the number and gets the latest one. How can I achieve this? I have `id` field which would be the latest one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreData get distinct values of Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000768/coredata-get-distinct-values-of-attribute)

Comment: Data wise yes, but not from the question.

Comment: You mean from the point of efficiency?

Comment: No. I gave update in terms of Messages for mac os. I want the max row of `id` group by on a certain column.

Comment: Oh, so you want to to group the rows by id, and then get the first row from each group?

Comment: I have `id`, `name`, `title`. I want to group by on `name` and get the largest `id` row for the `title`. make sense?

Comment: I think it does. Removing the close vote.